# MacOS - GoClipse GAE - "open build: No such file or directory"

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, compiler-errors, osx-lion, go

I've recently did a clean install of the MacOS Lion and I am having problems getting my Google App Engine Go applications to work in GoClipse again. I've downloaded XCode through App Store, the GAE Go SDK and Eclipse. I unzipped the Eclipse and SDK, installed GoClipse through Eclipse menu and moved 6g, 6l and pack files from GAE/goroot/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64 to GAE/goroot/bin. I've set up the appropriate directories in the Eclipse Preferences for Go, cleaned all the projects I have in my workspace and I got a ton of errors.

It appears that every single package got an error of "open build: No such file or directory". There are no other errors, just these ones, repeated over and over. I tried making a new project. When I added a blank .go file that stated just what package it is a part of, the same error appeared.

How should I go about fixing  the "open build" errors?

Answer (score 1):

Having tried using GoClipse recently, I have a vague memory that the error you're seeing is a leftover from a failed install.  The note I saw said to try and delete it (literally, select it in the window and hit delete/backspace key); it doesn't automatically disappear like with most other tools.

A bug for this is filed here : http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/issues/detail?id=104